# Putting axis labels with italics parallel to axes in R rgl package

Tags: r, special-characters, axis-labels, rgl

I am trying to create a 3D plot using the R package 'rgl.' I would like to have all axis labels parallel to the axes but las = 0 does not work and had no luck using text3d() or mtext3d(). Is it possible to do so, depending on your the figure you are seeing? Here are my codes:

```
X = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)
Y = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
Z = c(100, 220, 440, 660, 880, 1100)
df = data.frame(X, Y, Z)

#install.packages('rgl')
library(rgl)
# Cannot put axis labels parallel to the axes
plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'n', box = F, add = F,
xlab = 'Number of cars (N)',
ylab = 'Size (S)',
zlab = 'Weight (kg)')
plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'l', lwd = 2, add = T, col = 'blue')
rgl.snapshot('Figure1.png')
```

and this is what I get after trying to position axes as best as I can.

[image: Figure1.png]

I cannot even figure out this but ideally, I want to make letters in parentheses in italics but it would not let me use substitute and it is ignored. Here are my codes:

```
# Cannot use italics in the labels
plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'n', box = F, add = F,
xlab = substitute(paste('Number of cars (', italic('N'), ')')),
ylab = substitute(paste('Size (', italic('S'), ')')),
zlab = 'Weight (kg)')
plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'l', lwd = 2, add = T, col = 'blue')
rgl.snapshot('Figure2.png')
```

And I lose axis labels entirely.

[image: Figure2.png]

I have spent time searching for examples and documents but I cannot find any way to change the direction of axis labels or use italics. This is my first time using the rgl package and I appreciate any help!

New edits:

Thanks to the answer by user2554330, the labels can include italics but the labels are still positioned far from axes. Both of the following codes work and produce this figure (I can rotate the figure in the interactive window but at no moment all labels align with each axis).

```
plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'n', box = F, add = F,
xlab = expression(paste('Number of cars (', italic('N'), ')')),
ylab = expression(paste('Size (', italic('S'), ')')),
zlab = 'Weight (kg)')
plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'l', lwd = 2, add = T, col = 'blue')
rgl.snapshot('Figure3.png')

plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'n', box = F, add = F,
xlab = as.expression(substitute(paste('Number of cars (', italic('N'), ')'))),
ylab = as.expression(substitute(paste('Size (', italic('S'), ')'))),
zlab = 'Weight (kg)')
plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'l', lwd = 2, add = T, col = 'blue')
rgl.snapshot('Figure3.png')
```

[image: Figure3.png]

It would be ideal if I can also make all three axes starting from 0 at one of the corners but again, I could not make it happen by rotating the figure.

Comment: maybe convert the text to a sprite.  Then it can rotate, but will also scale as you zoom in and out (which perhaps you don't want).

Comment: related and possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357619/2761575

Comment: Thank you @dww for the post. I did search for similar examples but did not see this one, although I am not savvy enough to be able to decode the code example...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not using either a character or expression vector for your labels.  You need to use `expression()`, since `substitute()` produces a language object (which is an element of an expression vector).  (With your original code, I got the error  `Error in rep(text, len = newlen) :  attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'`  Don't ignore error messages!)

For example,

```
plot3d(df$X, df$Y, df$Z, type = 'n', box = F, add = F,
   xlab = expression(paste('Number of cars (', italic('N'), ')')),
   ylab = expression(paste('Size (', italic('S'), ')')),
   zlab = 'Weight (kg)')
```

If you really need to use `substitute` (e.g. to put a value in the label), then wrap it in `as.expression()`.

Comment: Thank you @user2554330, now I can have italics in my labels! I spent a lot of time searching to find the solution to this. I did see the error message but the problem is that I could not understand what it meant. R often gives me non-intuitive errors and I had thought it was one of those. I updated my post reflecting that but I still cannot figure out the alignment of the labels with axes.

Comment: Text is always horizontal in `rgl`.

Comment: So there is no way to add text or axis labels that is positioned parallel to axes in rgl?

Comment: If it's just a rectangle with the text printed on it you could position it wherever you like, but it's really hard to get that to look good (which is why rgl doesn't even try).

Comment: I was hoping that at least when you fix the figure at an angle you want to save, you can add texts at a (x, y, Z) location you want but I guess it is not possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.   Do it the way I told you.  You can look at the source to `plotmath3d` to create the texture to put on the rectangle, but don't use `sprites3d` to draw it:  put it on a `quads3d` object instead and rotate any way you like.  Expect to spend several hours on it.